# How to place controls in the footer?

Tags: ms-access

When I select some controls and add a table layout, the headings are placed in the form header. How can I place controls in the footer?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the Layout functions. -- You can cut and paste the labels from header to footer.

Comment: yes, but then, the controls are not in the same border layout anymore.

Comment: That's just how it is. A table layout has the headers at the top, not at the bottom. Not sure what you're expecting here.

Comment: there are many usecases, i.e. inputboxes for a filter, displaying the aggreagtes. I don't see why only use the header for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Soultion is easy. Just put some controls in the header, footer and normal area. Then select all and add the layout. After that, the new layout spans from the header to the footer:

[image]

[image]